# Neck discomfort after Overhead Press - is it serious?

Tags: squats, injury, pain, neck, overheadpress

I was doing overhead press and felt some pressure in my neck (I think I was straining my neck while I did them - weight was too heavy?). My neck was pretty sore after and I had trouble rotating it, but that went away after a day or two.

I did overhead press a week later; felt alright during the exercise, but afterwards, I had the same problem with my neck.

Two days later, I did back squats, and I think I aggravated the problem probably because sometimes my bar position wasn't ideal and it rested on a vertebrae for a little (shit).

There is no pain now, but a decent amount of discomfort that extends to my right upper back, and my neck's range of motion is a bit screwy.

**Is there a certain amount of time I should wait before convincing myself that this is a serious problem and not something that will go away in a couple of days?**

Side question: **Has anyone had this experience after overhead press - any tips?** However, I think there's a greater chance that this is because of the back squat.

**Edit:** It actually feels a little better when I press on my right upper back with my right hand. Not sure what that means. Lifting my right arm seems to alleviate pain - left arm not as much.

**Update:** Long over due, but nothing ever came out of this. I was fine in a few days. A now, a couple years later, no neck issues.

Comment: You have pain in your neck that isn't going away and is aggravated by continued exercise. We can't diagnose you, you need to get to a doctor and have it checked.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me after doing OHP once. I didn't think it was anything serious, and it wasn't. Rest for a couple of days and see how you feel.

Comment: No one on here will diagnose you but I can provide anecdotal  based thoughts. My solder always felt like it was clicking/popping on OHP and I would get a dull pain in it. I kept exercising it with weight at about 70% of my 1repmax and after a few months the pain went away. It seems the pain was linked to weakness in the muscle group. Consider using padding like a towel for back squats if you are pushing large numbers or lower the weight and work on form.

Comment: For what it's worth, the pain subsided after about three days.